# Remove Highcharts dataLabel border

Tags: javascript, highcharts, maps

I have some problems with Highcharts Maps library.
How can I remove the black dataLabels border?

Here are my settings:

```
var Map = $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0
    },

    series : [{

        mapData: Highcharts.maps['gbpostcodes'],

            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                fontSize:'20px',
                color:'yellow',
                borderWidth: 0,
                format: '{point.properties.Name}'
            }

    }]
});
```

(see attached screenshot)
[image]

Comment: No screenshot attached.

Comment: That's not a border, it's a text shadow.

Answer (score 18):

Highcharts V5 code for fixing this is

```
dataLabels: {
  style: {
    textOutline: 0
  },
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This did the job for me:

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
          dataLabels: {
            style: {
              textOutline: 0,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You sure can. See the API docs here regarding [dataLabels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels).
To remove the border set:

```
    dataLabels: {
    ...
    borderWidth: 0,
    ...
    },
```

If you are talking about the text shadows you can do this in your dataLabel as well:

```
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                fontSize: '20px',
                color: 'yellow',
                borderWidth: 0,
                format: '{point.properties.Name}',
                style: {
                    textShadow: false
                }
            },
```

Comment: This is not the case. Here are my settings

`dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      fontSize:'20px',
      color:'yellow',
      borderWidth: 0,
      format: '{point.properties.Name}'
}`

Comment: I m going to need to see more code or a representative example showing this. The `borderWidth: 0` should do it.

Comment: I have added my settings

Comment: I don't know whether it is a border or a shadow but params textShadow: false and borderWidth: 0 haven’t resolve the problem

Comment: @romvlads See my answer. I think `textShadow: null` instead of `textShadow: false` will fix the problem.

Comment: @romvlads, did you add `textShadow: false` under `dataLabels.style`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a column chart. I've solved the issue by using this in my `plotOptions.column`:

```
dataLabels: {
    /* ... */,
    style: {
        textShadow: null
    }
}
```

Does it work for you ?